# Java Xml Parser In Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

I am getting a Response in XML format

```
<item>
<title>
<![CDATA[
28. Februar 2013, FY/Q4 2012 Investoren-Telefonkonferenz
]]>
</title>
<author>
<![CDATA[ BAYER AG - Investorveranstaltungen ]]>
</author>
<pubDate>Thu, 28 Feb 2013 12:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
<description>
<![CDATA[
Rede von Dr. Marijn Dekkers, Vorsitzender des Vorstands der Bayer AG, Investoren-Telefonkonferenz zu den Ergebnissen des Geschaeftsjahres und des 4. Quartals 2012. (Auf...
]]>
</description>
<link>
http://www.webvideo.bayer.com/downloads/9208/9212/12312/file.mp3
</link>
<content:encoded>
<![CDATA[
<p>Rede von Dr. Marijn Dekkers, Vorsitzender des Vorstands der Bayer AG, Investoren-Telefonkonferenz zu den Ergebnissen des Geschaeftsjahres und des 4. Quartals 2012. (Auf Englisch)</p>
]]>
</content:encoded>
<category>ISIN_DE000BAY0017</category>
<category>ISIN_DE000BAY0017</category>
<category>podcast</category>
</item>
<item>
<title>
<![CDATA[
2013-01-30 - Analyst &amp; Investor Conference - Welcome Marc Spieker, Head of Investor Relations
]]>
</title>
<author>
<![CDATA[ E.ON Podcast ]]>
</author>
<pubDate>Wed, 30 Jan 2013 15:00:00 +0100</pubDate>
<description>
<![CDATA[ Analyst &amp; Investor... ]]>
</description>
<link>
http://www.thomson-webcast.net/de/portals/download.mp3?portal_id=315d3fce100b408b41a2c66bb982a367&presentation_id=d43466300a1a8ced8324011b593fb05a&video_id=24ae8f409449411695c0729760646bf7
</link>
<content:encoded>
<![CDATA[ <p>Analyst & Investor Conference</p> ]]>
</content:encoded>
<category>ISIN_DE000ENAG999</category>
<category>ISIN_DE000ENAG999</category>
<category>podcast</category>
</item>
```

I write a Parser to retrieve data from response .

But the  Problem is .When i test this in 2.1 device , It works as follows, I tested with Android 2.2 ,android 2.2.1 it works fine . Can any body tell me whats the problem

```
    <link>
      http://www.webvideo.bayer.com/downloads/9208/9212/12312/file.mp3
   </link>
```

I am able retrieve the link correctly
But when in another case , I failed

```
    <link>
     http://www.thomson-webcast.net/de/portals/download.mp3?portal_id=315d3fce100b408b41a2c66bb982a367&presentation_id=d43466300a1a8ced8324011b593fb05a&video_id=24ae8f409449411695c0729760646bf7
    </link>
```

When i parse the result is

```
 http://www.thomson-webcast.net/de/portals/download.mp3?portal_id=315d3fce100b408b41a2c66bb982a367
```

Data after `&` is missing  . I saw this only in android 2.1  .Can anybody Suggest me what could be wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the link text should be also in `CDATA` section, or have the `&` marks converted to `&amp;`

The `&presentation_id...` is considered as an (unresolved) XML entity.

Solution 1 (with `CDATA`):

```
<link>
    <![CDATA[http://www.thomson-webcast.net/de/portals/download.mp3?portal_id=315d3fce100b408b41a2c66bb982a367&presentation_id=d43466300a1a8ced8324011b593fb05a&video_id=24ae8f409449411695c0729760646bf7]]>
</link>
```

Solution 2 with `&amp;`:

```
<link>
    http://www.thomson-webcast.net/de/portals/download.mp3?portal_id=315d3fce100b408b41a2c66bb982a367&amp;presentation_id=d43466300a1a8ced8324011b593fb05a&amp;video_id=24ae8f409449411695c0729760646bf7
</link>
```

Comment: Try to change the server output. I put examples in the answer.

Comment: But my parser works correctly in other android Version . Only problem with Android 2.1

Comment: You can try a different parser, there may be differences between them. Actually, the 2.1 parser is correct: it its not a valid XML. It seems that later the parser was extended to be more *lean*, that's why this example is working on 2.2+ versions. So, the correct way is to change the server output.